# Connecting neutrals in disconnect switch

Tags: switch, neutral, splicing

Disconnects are an inexpensive way to connect two relatively large gauge conductors for 40-100A applications. However, most 240V disconnects only provide lugs for the two ungrounded conductors and the ground wires -- leaving no place to connect the neutral.

What's the best way to inexpensively bond the two neutrals when using 3-wire + ground cables? Large wire nuts are available, but I would prefer a lug-based connection, which seems more reliable at high currents. Polaris lugs are suitable but relatively costly. Does anyone have a more economical suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

For the 240V single-phase 60A circuit to my shop I used a 3-phase disconnect. It had 3 switched terminals, and also a ground lug bonded to the case itself. The inspector was fine with this approach.

Elsewhere for another project I used Polaris lugs which I got off eBay for a reasonable price, and were very easy to work with. Far simpler than using a split bolt and gobs of electrical tape and other supplies. But that said, a split bolt would work perfectly well if installed correctly.